# Where is documented the JBoss EAP runtime dependencies to be added in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using JBoss EAP 6.1 and Java EE 6.

JBoss tools add the JBoss runtime libraries, like `org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.cache.NoCache` on eclipse, but it fails to compile on maven because maven knows nothing about it.

I would like to add all JBoss EAP libraries through maven in order to build it successfully. Is it documented somewhere the artifacts I have to use to be able to add all JBoss EAP libraries in the classpath? Is there a single dependency I can add representing the whole Java EE 6 stack and its JBoss extensions like `org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.cache.NoCache`?

I was looking for something like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-eap</artifactId>
  <version>6.1</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then we just change `<version>6.2</version>` when we update the container and boom, magic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is in the pom.xml files included in the quickstarts bundled with JBoss.

From the kitchensink example:

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill 
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack (you can 
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras tools 
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate 
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with extras 
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The `${version.jboss.bom.eap}` is defined in the parent pom

```
    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom.eap>6.2.0.GA</version.jboss.bom.eap>
```

This is explained here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Development_Guide/Maven_BOM_Usage.html (requires redhat support account)

JBoss component versions are also listed here https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673